# Dados na listview (uwp)

Tags: c#, mysql

como mostrar as informações de um registro do banco MySQL em uma listview?

tentei assim mas não funcionou.

```
using (_connection = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection("Database=teste; Data Source=192.168.0.17;User Id=RFID;Password=1234;SslMode=None;"))
        {
            System.Text.EncodingProvider ppp;
            ppp = System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance;
            Encoding.RegisterProvider(ppp);

            _connection.Open();
            var cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT distinct id, Placa FROM test", _connection);

            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {

                    listView.Items.Add("Registro: " +reader.GetString("id") + reader.GetString("\nPlaca"));


                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O metodo `GetString`do `DataReader` espera um `int` como parâmetro e você está passando o nome do campo.
Existem duas formas de corrigir o erro:

Caso queira usar o `GetString` os nomes dos campos devem ser alterados para seus índices na query:

```
listView.Items.Add("Registro: " +reader.GetString(0) + reader.GetString(1));
```

Caso queira utilizar o nome dos campos você deverá utilizar o método `GetOrdinal` ficando assim:

```
listView.Items.Add("Registro: " +reader.GetOrdinal("id") + reader.GetOrdinal("Placa"));
```